# Using HTML5 Ajax form attributes not working with ASP.NET MVC, still being redirected to the Action url

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, html

When the submit button is clicked it goes into the `GetProducts` action method of my controller which returns a list of dates in **JSON** that I will be handling in the success function.

However, I keep getting redirected to `Products/GetProducts` and see the **JSON** list of dates in the web browser on an empty page. This is normal if ajax is not being used, but I thought I specified that I want this form to be AJAX in the form attributes..

My ultimate goal is to retrieve the dates and then add them to a `div` on the page without any page redirects or flicker.

**form declaration:**

```
<form asp-action="GetProducts" id="myForm" data-ajax="true" data-ajax-method="POST" data-ajax-success="myForm_AjaxSuccess">
    <input type="submit" value="Generate Products" class="btn btn-default" />
</form>
```

**the success js function:**

```
function myForm_AjaxSuccess(data) {
    alert(data);
}
```

**action method:**

```
    // POST: Products/GetProducts
    [HttpPost]
    //[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public IActionResult GetProducts(ProductViewModel vm)
    {

        IList<DateTime> dateList = new List<DateTime>()
        {
            new DateTime(2012, 01, 12),
            new DateTime(2012, 02, 12,
            new DateTime(20162, 03, 12)
        };

        return Json(dateList);
    }
```

Note that this form is being opened up inside of a [Telerik Kendo Dialog](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/window/index) Window if it makes any difference. I am not sure why that would prevent the ajax from working when the form is submitted.

---

**Here is my alternate way of doing it for now which is working perfectly, but I want to get it working using the html5 ajax helpers as described above:**

```
$('#myForm').submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/Products/GetProducts",
        data: $('#myForm').serialize(),
        datatype: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I came across an issue like this not to long ago and found out I hadnt included the jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js script. Once I included that script, the ajax form worked correctly.

Comment: Hmm well I definitely have all of that being included. However the form is in a dialog window, I wonder if this could have anything to do with it.

Comment: The `data-ajax-*` attributes are not supported in MVC-6 - its been dropped along with the `Ajax.BeginForm()`, `Ajax.ActionLink()` etc methods

Answer (score 0):

@BlakeRivelll: Nothing is preventing AJAX from working (as you mentioned in your question) as the application does go into the "GetProducts" method inside the Controller.

Could you specify the "dataType" in the AJAX call as "json"? You are expecting a JSON return type and not html, yes?

"dataType" is what you're expecting back from the server: json, html, text, etc. jQuery will use this to figure out how to populate the success function's parameter.

Comment: I want to make sure we are on the same page. The bottom part of my post is how I got it working without using the HTML5 ajax attributes. The above portion shows me trying to get it working using the HTML5 ajax attributes and it is redirecting me to Products/GetProducts which means ajax isn't being used doesn't it? And yes I changed dataType to json sorry about that. It is my understanding that when using the HTML5 ajax tag helpers I don't need to write all of the AJAX stuff out like I am doing at the bottom of my post. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @BlakeRivell: As you are being redirected to Products/GetProducts and the dateList is being shown on that View, I tend to believe that the GetProducts method is being hit via AJAX (which would mean that the AJAX call is being made). I believe that the return data type for the AJAX is being set to html by default (and hence the redirection to its own View).
I haven't used Telerik Kendo specifically, but have come across a similar situation using AJAX in .NET MVC 4.

Comment: So what you are saying is that I need to find an HTML5 ajax attribute that allows me to set the dataType from the default? I assumed the whole unobtrusive thing handles that stuff for your automatically, but I guess not. I also assumed that regardless of the dataType I shouldn't be getting redirected when making an ajax call.